# RDF Rank in GraphDB over saved graph

Tags: sparql, graphdb, knowledge-graph

I am getting an error when running the RDF Rank plugin in GraphDB over a saved graph.

I am not able to run RDF Rank over individuals only in my GraphDB.

1. I wrote the following script (in "Explore -> Visual graph") that returns a graph consisting of all the individuals (and no classes) from my DB:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
CONSTRUCT {?individual ?a ?z}
WHERE {
    ?individual rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
    ?individual ?a ?z .
    ?z rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
}
```

2. I save the graph in "Explore -> Visual graph" as a saved graph
3. I copy the URL of the saved graph in "Explore -> Visual graph" ("Get URL to graph" button)
4. In "Setup -> RDF Rank" I include the saved graph in "Included" to run RDF Rank only over this graph by pasting it
5. When I press "Compute Full" I get the following error: "ERROR Selected filter does not return any statements." (see picture)

[image]

Comment: If you save the result of the CONSTRUCT query in a new repository-and use the repository link as the RDF Rank "Included Graph", does it work? My concern is that the visualizations aren't queryable

Comment: you could also use SPARQL Update, i.e. an `WITH <SOME_GRAPH_URI> INSERT {} WHERE {}` instead of the `CONSTRUCT {} WHERE {}` statement to put your visual graph into a separate named graph. I'm sure on graph `<SOME_GRAPH_URI>` computing the RDF rank will work

Comment: @Thomas this seems to be a bad idea because I want to have all my scripts and computations in the same repository

Comment: @UninformedUser could you provide additional information or a full answer with a SPARQL script please? I couldn't find any information about a `WITH` statement

Comment: My point is that the link you provide to your visualization isn't a SPARQL endpoint, which could be why the error message is letting you know that it can't get any triples out. It's a visualization platform-not a queryable graph repository. To use RDF Rank, put your triples in a queryable repository.

Comment: @Thomas Ok I understand... however I think this should be possible with GraphDB somehow. In the end it's a complete RDF database, not only a visualization platform? If you could provide a sample script how to create a new repository from another one (with a SPARQL script or another way) that would be very nice.

Comment: As I suggested, try to use a proper named graph. The template I provided is basically almost your query, just with different keywords. Without the `WITH` keyword it is just `INSERT {GRAPH <https://visualize-me.org/> { ?individual ?a ?z } }
WHERE {
    ?individual rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
    ?individual ?a ?z .
    ?z rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
}` and then use the graph name `https://visualize-me.org/` in the include list of RDF rank.

Comment: @UninformedUser it worked that way, first I tried it in the visual graph SPARQL code editor without success, after I tried it in the SPARQL code editor where it created a new named graph. Thanks again.